# How to do a query with that structure in Firebase + Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have always used SQL databases, now, im trying to understand Firebase database.

With this structure :

**User -> RandomID -> email, name, password**

what is the best way to select the user with name "Peter" ?

I have seen in tutorials the use of random id's to create children, that's why i use it.

with

```
databaseReference.child("User").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{}
```

I can read all users (I could filter in the code) but i want do a correct listener, but the problem is that i dont know the "ID" (because it is random), why do people use it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orderByChild` and `equalTo` in Firebase realtime database

```
databaseReference.child("User").orderByChild("name").equalTo("Peter").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{}
```

The only thing is that firebase realtime database does not allow compose queries if you want to filter by name and let's say email, you should use the new Firestore database which has more queries capabilities

Please check this source on how to do queries with realtime database

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=en#ordering-by-value

Comment: works!! but.. really, i dont get why i dont need the randomID... in my logic it should be... databaseReference.child("User").child(**RANDOMID***).orderByChild("name").equalTo("Peter").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{}

Comment: it maps the keys below your User child that matchs the childname "name" then it justs returns the ones that are equalTo("peter") , then after that inside your addValueEventListener you can use getKey() to get which randomID contains those Peter values

Comment: If you just want to filter inside your own node , there is no need of a query, you can just access one time to that node and get the value of name